# Trusted Call Recorder for Android

Tags: android, voice-recording

There are plenty of such applications on Google Play, but it's hard to understand who to trust (I know about application permissions). Which call recorder would you recommend, preferably from big known company?

Comment: When it comes to trust, it's much better to check with F-Droid as source for your apps. And when it comes to personal data, it's best to avoid trackers (which is usually covered by using F-Droid – but rarely by "big known companies"). You can find some call recorders [here in my list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_98), and [Call Recorder](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.github.axet.callrecorder/) would probably be a good candidate (author has several trusted apps on F-Droid). Not using a call recorder myself, so only a comment…

Comment: @Izzy thanks for links, Call Recorder records only my voice by the way, I'll continue to look for.

Comment: @Izzy about trackers: what if call recorder tracks me? Is it differs in some way from any other application tracks us? And I don't use a phone for a web-browsing.

Comment: @Izzy I've found suitable application by the way, CallRecorder for Android from f-droid.org does it. Thanks.

Comment: "records only my voice": see the description. This might well be a limitation of your device/ROM. As for tracking: IMHO that's always bad, right. But the more "personal" the details are, the worse it is. With a call recorder, data most likely include whom you talked to and when. So it's not "just your own data", but also personal data of the person you talk with. If you personally don't care (or "accept out of resignation"), you cannot definitely say the same for all other people. Agreed, most have "given up", but not all ;)

Comment: Ui, that crossed. Glad to read you've found a solution! Mind to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)?

Comment: @Izzy `Ui, that crossed`, what ?

Comment: I've posted my longer comment while you were posting your finding, so I saw your comment the same moment I submitted mine ;) And glad to see it was not a device restriction then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Call recorder for Android](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.callrecorder.android/) (version 25) from f-droid.org records both your and incoming voices. Works on Android 7.1.2.